# Express middleware is executing twice if headers are passed with request?

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm newbie in Node js I'm using express framework for this

My middleware is running twice if I'm passing headers to it below is my set-up

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3003;
const app = express();


app.use( function(req, res, next){
    console.log('This is called twice when headers are passed in request:');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    next();
});


app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('hey im called');
    res.send({message: 'hi'})
});


const server = app.listen(port, function(error){
    if (error){
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
    return
    }
    console.log(`server is listining on ${port}, ${this}`)
});
```

call from browser console `$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:3003', headers: {  x: 1 , y: 1}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are making AJAX call from a different domain than `localhost:3003` browser will first send the `pre-flight option` call, before the actual API.

You can find more details on `pre-flight` or `CORS` [Here](https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024)

Solution:
You can render the html page on root url `/` which will contain the `ajax` call and place your existing api route as

`app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('hey im called');
    res.send({message: 'hi'})
});`

and your ajax call would be

`$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:3003/test', headers: {  x: 1 , y: 1}})`